# "protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?" when using docker with ray

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ray

I am getting the following error when using docker with ray:

```
Digest: sha256:2c0f86c6209e02d1f9e3d0a611ac04d73c3ed132b8b9319a28e2069f1503fb53
Status: Downloaded newer image for us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/sleep-detection/v1:latest
us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/sleep-detection/v1:latest
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64/v2) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
b2567e6280d5124da59fec72d17f89e15ceaa866b991830c8a747df988334e60
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.3]
Shared connection to 34.82.93.47 closed.
2023-11-26 20:17:52,373 INFO node.py:321 -- wait_for_compute_zone_operation: Waiting for operation operation-1701051472184-60b18e8be856a-ab18acec-f1df8579 to finish...
2023-11-26 20:17:57,644 INFO node.py:340 -- wait_for_compute_zone_operation: Operation operation-1701051472184-60b18e8be856a-ab18acec-f1df8579 finished.
  New status: update-failed
  !!!
  SSH command failed.
  !!!

  Failed to setup head node.
```

Could you help me what would be going wrong here? My config looks like this:

```
# A unique identifier for the head node and workers of this cluster.
cluster_name: minimal
max_workers: 1
# Cloud-provider specific configuration.
provider:
    type: gcp
    region: us-west1
    project_id: [project-id]
    availability_zone: us-west1-a

docker:
  image: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/sleep-detection/v1
  container_name: test
  pull_before_run: true
  run_options:
    - --detach

available_node_types:
  ray_head_default:
    node_config:
      machineType: e2-standard-2
      disks:
        - boot: true
          autoDelete: true
          initializeParams:
            diskSizeGb: 50
            sourceImage: projects/ml-images/global/images/c0-deeplearning-common-cpu-v20230925-debian-10

      serviceAccounts:
        - email: ray-autoscaler-sa-v1@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com
          scopes:
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

    resources:
      CPU: 2

  ray_worker_default:
    min_workers: 0
    max_workers: 1
    node_config:
      machineType: e2-standard-2
      disks:
        - boot: true
          autoDelete: true
          initializeParams:
            diskSizeGb: 10
            sourceImage: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2304-lunar-amd64-v20231030
            diskType: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/zones/us-west1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard
      serviceAccounts:
        - email: ray-autoscaler-sa-v1@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com
          scopes:
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
    resources:
      CPU: 2

head_node_type: ray_head_default

initialization_commands:
  - gcloud auth configure-docker us-west1-docker.pkg.dev --quiet
```

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176986/rsync-gives-protocol-version-mismatch-on-clean-shell-wsl-debian

Comment: Nope didn't. I used a sample docker image (from google) but found the same error.

Comment: I also tried using a given image from the list of public images and tried using a sample docker image, and getting the same error. Looks like it's not my configuration that is causing the issue.